# VMware ESXI Genshin Impact with Windows 10 OS (Hide virtualization from guest OS)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, gaming, esxi

As the title says I'm trying to get Genshin Impact to run on a Windows 10 VM on VMware ESXI version 6.7. It's taken quite a long time but so far I've managed to set up a VM with a NVidia Geforce 2070 passed through to the vm. I added the line `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"` to the vmx file and hooked up a dummy monitor to the GPU to allow Parsec to remotely connect to it. I've tested several games such as Minecraft Java Edition, Subnautica Below Zero(running on Steam), and Rocket League(running on the Epic Games Launcher) and they all work fine.
After looking for a while on line I've come up with several more lines to add to the vmx file that seem to fix a similar problem with a game called Sword of the New World. However, when I run Genshin Impact it still comes up with a gui saying "Sorry, this application cannot run under a Virtual Machine."
I have also found that if running the vm off of KVM with Linux(which I am not willing to do after spending three weeks teaching myself how to setup ESXI with a VM that can be remotely accessed with parsec) apparently upon adding

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'>
    ...
    <feature policy='disable' name='hypervisor'/>
</cpu>
```

to the xml file, Genshin Impact works just fine.
I feel that there must be an equivalent string I can add to the vmx file for VMware ESXI that would do the same thing but after quite a bit of research I haven't found anything that works. I've come across a lot of users and forums that explain that it will not work on Shadow or virtual box, but nothing about VMware or esxi. Does anybody know an equivalent command for ESXI?

.vmx file:

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "14"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
numvcpus = "6"
memSize = "11264"
bios.bootRetry.delay = "10"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
tools.upgrade.policy = "manual"
sched.cpu.units = "mhz"
sched.cpu.affinity = "all"
vm.createDate = "1602110300706076"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsisas1068"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
scsi0:0.fileName = "Nix_1.vmdk"
sched.scsi0:0.shares = "normal"
sched.scsi0:0.throughputCap = "off"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet0.networkName = "VM Network"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
sata0:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
sata0:0.fileName = "/vmfs/volumes/5f7df0e5-3420089e-16a9-002655daae9a/os_images/Windows.iso"
sata0:0.present = "TRUE"
displayName = "Nix"
guestOS = "windows9-64"
toolScripts.afterPowerOn = "TRUE"
toolScripts.afterResume = "TRUE"
toolScripts.beforeSuspend = "TRUE"
toolScripts.beforePowerOff = "TRUE"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
uuid.bios = "56 4d e9 ca 46 e7 34 5c-b4 66 e3 ce a8 07 1c ac"
uuid.location = "56 4d e9 ca 46 e7 34 5c-b4 66 e3 ce a8 07 1c ac"
vc.uuid = "52 9a c9 a3 02 99 09 28-07 36 8d 25 db 2c be cf"
sched.cpu.min = "0"
sched.cpu.shares = "normal"
sched.mem.min = "11264"
sched.mem.minSize = "11264"
sched.mem.shares = "normal"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:07:1c:ac"
vmci0.id = "-1475928916"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
sata0:0.startConnected = "TRUE"
nvme0.present = "TRUE"
config.readOnly = "FALSE"
extendedConfigFile = "Nix_1.vmxf"
sound.autoDetect = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.allowGuestConnectionControl = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
svga.vramSize = "268435456"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
pciPassthru0.present = "TRUE"
pciPassthru1.present = "TRUE"
pciPassthru0.id = "00000:010:00.0"
pciPassthru0.deviceId = "0x1e84"
pciPassthru0.vendorId = "0x10de"
pciPassthru0.systemId = "5f74b25d-327c-6a86-6713-002655daae9a"
pciPassthru1.id = "00000:010:00.1"
pciPassthru1.deviceId = "0x10f8"
pciPassthru1.vendorId = "0x10de"
pciPassthru1.systemId = "5f74b25d-327c-6a86-6713-002655daae9a"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "6"
svga.numDisplays = "2"
svga.autodetect = "FALSE"
tools.guest.desktop.autolock = "FALSE"
nvram = "Nix_1.nvram"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
svga.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
RemoteDisplay.maxConnections = "1"
sched.cpu.latencySensitivity = "medium"
disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"
numa.autosize.cookie = "60001"
numa.autosize.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode = "6"
sched.swap.derivedName = "/vmfs/volumes/5f7df0e5-3420089e-16a9-002655daae9a/Nix_1/Nix_1-0b2ace3b.vswp"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "192"
usb_xhci.pciSlotNumber = "224"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "32"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
scsi0.sasWWID = "50 05 05 6a 46 e7 34 50"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vm.genid = "-1816076186780706416"
vm.genidX = "-8688614713756288280"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "43"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "268435456"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "0"
nvme0.pciSlotNumber = "256"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "3"
sched.mem.pin = "TRUE"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
pciPassthru0.pciSlotNumber = "1184"
pciPassthru1.pciSlotNumber = "1216"
migrate.hostLog = "./Nix_1-0b2ace3b.hlog"
scsi0:0.redo = ""
monitor_control.virtual_rdtsc = "false"
monitor_control.restrict_backdoor = "true"
isolation.tools.getPtrLocation.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.setPtrLocation.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.setVersion.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.getVersion.disable = "true"
monitor_control.disable_directexec = "true"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "4"
usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
```

This is what I got for `systeminfo` in the vm windows command line:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: No
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: No
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

And yes the virtual machine name is Latin for snow. I themed them.
Also let me know if you need any more info. I'd be happy to comply.